# How to re-download a corrupted music track from iTunes store

Tags: itunes

I downloaded Richard Thompson's "Acoustic Rarities" album this evening.

Unfortunately track 10, "Sloth", cuts out after about 15 seconds with a glitchy sound and then silence.

I assume the download is corrupted. It is a shame that iTunes doesn't do a basic md5 or checksum check on the downloaded file so it knows that it needs fixing.

I have tried the obvious thing which is right-click on the track, "Remove Download" and then download it again. However the subsequent download is rather fast, and the track has the same glitch. I assume the file is cached somewhere.

Is there a cache on my computer that I could delete and re-download? Is there a way to trick iTunes into trying again properly?

I have iTunes 12.7.0.166 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was:

1. right-click on the track, "Remove Download"
2. play the track anyway, i.e. so it plays 'from the cloud'... it played all the way through without a glitch
3. now download the track again

Voilà, it's fixed.

Re @atlex2's comment below. I checked the following:

I'm on macOS and iTunes 12.9.5.5 ... for an album downloaded from iTunes store (not Apple Music) I can right-click on a single track and select "Remove Download" (Note: not "Delete from Library" and not the whole album). At this point the track shows this icon:
[image]

Clicking the cloud with arrow icon will download the track again from iTunes.

But see full method above for solving issue with glitchy track.

Comment: This made it disappear from my itunes without any way to re-download-- without Apple Music, YMMV

Comment: Actually, you can find it in Account->Purchases, but it locks something for 90 days that I don't understand.

Comment: maybe we have different versions, have added more detail

Comment: Yeah, doesn't for me (not using iTunes match or Apple Music)

Answer (score 1):

For me the same track results in pure silence.

Please contact Apple's iTunes team regarding this issue (iTunes > Store > View my Account > purchases > 'Report a problem'). This is nothing you can solve on your own. Apple has to fix the issue with the track in order for you to download the correct song.

Comment: are you on Windows?  I have no "purchases" menu and can't find any "Report a problem" link

Comment: https://reportaproblem.apple.com Here!